# Programming style: iterate over elements within function or outside

Tags: function, loops, coding-style

This question is I think general about programming, but in my case I am programming in Python. Lets say I have a list of elements and for each element I want to apply a function. What is the better programming style:
-To have a loop outside the function, which calls the function for each element

```
for element in list:
   if element furfills criteria:
      f(element)

def f(element):
   return dosomething(element)
```

-To make the function get the whole list and handle the whole list on itself.

```
def f(list)
   if f==singleElement:
      return f(list)
   else:
      for element in list:
         if element furfills criteria:
            doSomething(element)
```

Comment: I would define two functions: one for the element and one for the list. Careful with that circular definition: `def f(list): return f(list)`

Comment: had the same idea, too!